# copy a file from remote to local using cat

Tags: linux, copy, cat

using terminal or Putty I ssh to a remote server.

Is it possible to `cat` a file, save the output of the terminal locally and recreate the file using only output of the terminal?

Comment: cat a file, you get the file content as output, so what you want is just download the file from remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just try something like this:

```
ssh -l user ${REMOTE_SERVER} "cat /path/to/remote/file" > /path/to/local/file
```